# NSInternalInconsistencyException wrong section number in table view?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiview

I have a UITableView in my UIView, that has variable number of sections, depending on some conditions. I am receiving the exception below.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table
>   view after the update (1) must be equal to the number of sections
>   contained in the table view before the update (2), plus or minus the
>   number of sections inserted or deleted (1 inserted, 0 deleted).

From the error it seems that I have different number of sections in the datasource???
How do I resolve the problem?

This is my interface:

```
@interface bookDetailView :  SomeView <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource> 
{
    UITableView *bookDetailTableView;
        ....
}
```

Here is my view initialization

```
UIView *view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame] autorelease];
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
self.view = view;

UITableView *tableView = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:view.bounds style:UITableViewStyleGrouped] autorelease];
tableView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = self;
tableView.sectionIndexMinimumDisplayRowCount = 20;

bookDetailTableView = tableView;
[self.view addSubview:bookDetailTableView];
```

The code crashes at insertSections ....

```
if (![book method1])
{
    [bookDetailTableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(1,1)] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
else
{
     [bookDetailTableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(2,1)] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

numberOfSectionsInTableView

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView  
{
    if (editMode)
    {


        if(newbookFlag || listBook )
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else 
        {
            if(![book preferable])
            {
                return 2;
            }
            else
            {
                return 3;
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Any idea? I tried beginUpdates and endUpdates and the problem is still there.

Comment: what values are " numberOfSectionsinTable " and "numberOfRowsinTableView" functions returning

Comment: @AppleDelegate how do I print it? via NSLog???

Comment: Yes.. Via NSLog.. You can find @ what case you are getting the exception.. As answered by @Niels the modification you made to the section should be reflected to `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insert a section into a UITableView you should make sure that this change is reflected in your dataSource. In this case your numberOfSectionsInTableView: method should return one additional row upon inserting the new section.

Comment: so the code modification should be done in the numberOfSectionsInTableView?

Comment: well you should make some change before calling insertSections: so that numberOfSectionsInTableView returns the number of sections before the insertion plus the number of sections you are inserting.

Comment: can you post your numberOfSectionsInTableView implementation? then maybe I can clarify

Comment: I just edited my question with portion of the function. I think that you will get the idea

Comment: what variable represents my data source here? Do I need an NSMutableArray in my interface?

Comment: based on the exception I can see that you are returning 2 sections before you call insertSection: and you are returning 1 afterwards. numberOfSectionsInTableView should return 3 if you are adding 1 section to the already existing 2

Answer (score 0):

I actually received this error due to a slight red-herring. I had a model of the table sections and table cells within them that I use to manage the cells in memory before they are rendered on screen. In my particular case I was attempting to find the index of the deleted cell using the [NSArray indexOfObject:cell] method. As the cell had of course been removed from the collection already, rather than throwing an exception, objective-c returned me the int max value which led to the exception exhibited in this question as I then created an NSIndexPath from the values returned which were subsequently invalid.